Will a 149 inch built in desk sag in the middle?
We just had a built-in desk installed across the length of our home office. The entire desktop is 149 inches long and 25 inches wide (made of 5 planks glued together). There is a cabinet on each side, measuring approximately 36 inches wide, so the center span of the desk is 75 inches, enough for two chairs. The desktop is made of solid maple and is 1.5 inches thick. Our contractor who installed it was very confident in its stability and sturdiness. I am just looking for the opinions and advice of others, as I don't want a problem later on down the road!

Plugging your numbers into the Sagulator (https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/), I tend to agree with your contractor that it will be fine. Btw, you did not specify the load. I assumed around 30 kg max.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. The Sagulator will take you far in assessing how much deflection you can expect of any 'shelf' (a span of wood, whether a formal shelf or not) but as a non-woodworker some basics to help. First off, go into it overstating loads etc. (in short, make it a worst-case scenario on steroids) so that there's zero chance the predicted deflection will give you a false sense of security — in the past I have for example doubled the expected load and still gotten an acceptable result so that there's absolutely no chance the shelf will disappoint the user in service. [contd]

2nd, doesn't matter that the desk is made up of 5 planks; once glued together properly they become a single piece, so you can ignore that. 3rd, this is maple, which is a hardwood with good stiffness. And while 75" is certainly a large span do remember this is just a desk, not a bookcase shelf in a law office, or the travelogue section of the local library! Given the era I imagine it will not need to support two giant CRTs :-) .....which it could BTW! So even grossly over-estimating the expected load and clicking on Center load I'm sure you'll end up with an acceptable predicted deflection.
